# pass argument to function when creating object of class

Tags: php, oop

I am creating an object of a class as follows:

```
$model = new Jobsites('search') ;
```

The class looks like:

```
class Jobsites extends BaseJobsites
{
    public function search($id=0)
    {
        echo $id;
    }
}
```

Now here, when I am creating an object by code `new Jobsites('search')`.

Here search is function and i want to pass argument to this function like `search(10)`

How can I do that? how to pass argument to function in object creation ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Can you clarify, please?

Comment: I totally agree @Gordon

Comment: Do you mean making a constructor and set `$this->id = $id` and get it by using `echo $this->id`?

Comment: i am creating object new Jobsites('search') where search is function and here i want to pass argument so how to do that?

Comment: `$model = new Jobsites(); $model->search(23);` would echo 23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the comments I think you mean this:

```
class Jobsites extends BaseJobsites
{
   public function __construct($myFunction, $myId){
      $this->$myFunction($myId);
   } 

   private function search($id=0)
   {
        echo $id;
   }
}


$class = new Jobsites('search',1);
```

Comment: we can not pass argument direct in new Jobsites('search') like new Jobsites('search(10)') or anything???

Comment: No that is not possible. You could however do something else I'll edit my question.

Comment: ok friend thanks, i have asked that simple question so why down voted these much :(

Comment: Thanks friend, i need exactly the same

Comment: Just a note... May be it will be more reusable to do something like this: call_user_func(array($this, $myFunction), $myId); Or concider using call_user_func_array